# WPF - Set child controls of a user control to be readonly using binding

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF application with many different controls. I need to be able to set all child controls to be read only based on a property in my view model that I want to bind to.

There are a couple of challenges that I see:

1. How to ensure that setting the parent control to read only, also sets the child controls
2. Not all controls have a ReadOnly property - some IsReadOnly, some only have an IsEnabled

Has anyone any views on a generic solution rather than me having to bind the appropriate property (ReadOnly, IsReadOnly, etc) for each individual control?

Is there some way that I could use an attached property? Is there anyway, for example, that I could set a property on a grid, then in the code iterate through each child control setting it's appropriate property (if applicable at all)?

Any ideas welcomed.

David

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to do this using WPF implicit styles. The style would contain the Binding to the view model, for example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotProcessing}" />
</Style>
```

As this style does not have the `x:Key` attribute set and uses the `x:Type` markup extension on the `TargetType` attribute, it is implicitly applied to all buttons in this case.

You would have to write an implicit style for each distinct control in your view as the following style would not be applied to all your buttons, text boxes and whatever controls you use (although the `IsEnabled` property is defined on `FrameworkElement`):

```
<!-- This implicit style is not applied as the x:Type must be the same type as 
     the targeted control; inheritance does not work here. -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsNotProcessing}" />
</Style>
```

Another option would be to make a single style that has a resource key an then reference this from every control, which is also quite cumbersome, but could be done relatively easy using Blend if you know all the controls at design time (you would select all controls and then apply the style using the properties window).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work through this is in my scenario...maybe I was trying to make things more complicated than they need to be

Answer (score -1):

Use the property IsHitTestVisible in xaml file to make real read only

```
<Grid IsHitTestVisible = "False">
//put a control
</Grid>
```

Comment: No, don't do that. The controls are still accessible when IsHitTestVisible is set to False (using `Tab` for instance).